# DHCP server in separate broadcast domain and option 82

Tags: dhcp, ip-address

Recently studies of DHCP servers raise some questions, which I cannot find the answers to using Google.
Many documentations state: "If there is only one subnet declaration, and no network interfaces are in the range of that subnet, the DHCP daemon fails to start."

1. Can I set up a DHCP server, which resides in separate location/broadcast domain, the function of which just leasing IP addresses, and the interface addresses of this DHCP server are not in the range of subnet declarations, and the DHCP server does not know about router, the IP address of which it provides to users as the gateway during the lease. (Actually I can give some "dummy" alias IP address in interfaces which belong to subnet declaration, just for the workaround purpose only)
2. Just very curious after studying option 82: can I provide for a single port (user) not just a single IP address but a subnet network? Or it is the completely different scope of question?

Comment: it may help point your answer to people that can answer it, and help them answer it, if you also add some practical part to the question so, mention the dhcp daemon you are trying to use to do this and give commands / settings showing what you want to do.  And when you add into your question what dhcp daemon you are using, you can use that as a tag in your question

Comment: To Number 1: Yes, it is possible see the following link:
https://superuser.com/questions/859280/dhcp-server-in-separate-broadcast-domain-and-option-82